# Odoo - auto refreshing page when on specific view

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo, openerp-7

I need to auto refresh the page when I'm on my custom view. But I don't seem to find a solution for that.

First I tried to use `auto_refresh` attribute in action, but it seems it only works on GTK client (old GUI used in OpenERP version 6 and older) and does not on web. Like this:

```
    <record id="action_123" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">My action</field>
        <field name="res_model">model.name</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="domain">[('state','=','open')]</field>

        <field name="view_id" eval="False"/>
        <field name="context">{
                'search_default_not_printed': 1,
            }
        </field>
    </record>
```

As I said, this one does not do anything.

Then I tried to add javascript inside tree view, but I just get error, that you can't use `script`. Script I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 5000);
</script>
```

Does anyone know how can I add such or similar script on tree view, so it would refresh the page after x seconds? Or if there is better way to do that, I'm open to suggestions of course.

Comment: Hi Andrius,
I also have a similar requirement, I need to refresh the view on write(). If you have a solution for this, do update.

Thanks And Regards

Comment: Hi andrius, i'm working on that, i have the some problem. I modified this file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150523\server\openerp\addons\test_module\static\src\js\graph_widget.js by adding this line setInterval(function(){self.pivot.update_data().then(self.proxy('display_data'));},5000); in the start function , but this refresh all the pages every 5 seconds.

Comment: I try also to redefine the graph_widget.js file in my own module, but this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Anyone got to a solution on this ?

Answer (score 1):

For Odoo 8.0, add this two modules

[bus_enhanced](https://github.com/szufisher/web/tree/8.0/bus_enhanced)
[web_auto_refresh](https://github.com/szufisher/web/tree/8.0/web_auto_refresh)

Go to **Settings > Technical > Actions > Windows Actions**, look for your action id and set `auto_refresh` to any value greater than 0.

Enjoy

**Obs:** It doesn't reload at time intervals, instead it connects to the server to check if the underlying model has changed. So if your view isn't bound to any model it will not work.